# Google Sheets - Formula for If Cell A is exactly Option X (from a dropdown menu) then Link to Cell B

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to write a formula that will paste a link on Cell A (ex: G5) to Cell C (U5 on the same spreadsheet) if Cell B (H5) is exactly Option X (ex: "General Event") from a dropdown menu with 5 different text-based options. However, Cell C is a link to a Google Drive folder.

Does such a formula exist? Help me please :D

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.